# Does the Charts library support showing a message when there's no data to display?

Tags: ios-charts

I'm using the Charts library ([Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)) and I want to display a message on the chart if there's no data to display - something like this:

[image]

I've read the documentation, searched the code base, and searched the issues on Github and the only thing I could find is an [old issue](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/975) that suggests `ChartViewBase` has a property called `noDataTextDescription`. As far as I can tell, that's not in the Charts 3.1.1 code.

There is a `chartDescription` property, but that only shows a description in the bottom right corner of the chart. Is this intended to be used for a message like 'There's no data to display`?

Comment: did you check my answer ?

Comment: @CodeChanger sorry, not yet but I’ll check this morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer version after 3.X many properties name updated and as per your requirement for No Data Text you can use below property for the same.

```
lineChartView.noDataText = "<Your custom Text>"
```

Hope this will help to show Message while there is no data.